# Storing form data in MongoDB (Design Question)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

Trying to design a Form Entry web app and i've rarely used MongoDB before.

Wondering if this is the best practice for storing form (document) data inside a collection.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


// Create Schema and Model
const documentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    nps: [{ // New Promotion Submission
        documentId: Number,
        orgid: Number,
        documentFields: [{ // Form Fields
            id: Number,
            dateTimeSubmitted: Date,
            title: String,
            productDescription: String,
            productUnitSize: Number,
            productCartonQty: Number 
        }]
    }]
})
const documents = mongoose.model('documents', documentSchema);

module.exports = documents;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely fine design, couple of things to look at:

1. Make sure you introduce [validation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) on your schema fields, mirror the same validation pattern on the frontend form fields also.
2. Be consistent with your naming: if you use camelCase in documentId make sure to also origId
3. Convention says you name a model in singular form, i.e. "Document" not "documents".
4. If you're going to re-use the *documentFields* schema anywhere else in other models, make sure to store it as a separate schema and import as needed.